# A TeX example that fails to keep the sequence of floats

Tags: floats, positioning

I wish to have a TeX example which includes text, figures and tables, where the sequence of elements in the resulting DVI is NOT as it is in the TeX file.

I am looking for this so to see how well different solutions can fix this.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, because LaTeX keeps the floats in a FIFO queue. It can happen when you use the `[H]` specifier provided by the **float** package (which I never recommend). Of course, text is mostly independent of floats, because the very purpose of floats is that LaTeX chooses the "best" place where to put them.

Comment: Hi egreg, I rephrased my question in the hopes of making it clearer.  I think it is obviously possible to do (since I get this effect in some of my files, which I try to correct using H), I just do not know how to create a good dummy example :)

Comment: This actually can happen if you mix one column and two column floats in a two column document (because the queues are different). I'd be very curious to see an example where this happens in a one column document (without using pseudofloats with `[H]`).

Comment: @TalGalili: Further to egreg's comment, read the entry on the UK TeX FAQ about [Two-column float numbers out of order](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2colfltorder).

Comment: @TalGalili We will need a minimal example to offer more than rather general statements

Comment: @TalGalili -- The url for the UK TeX FAQ has changed.  Use this instead: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2colfltorder .

Answer (score 2):

Does the following example produce the results you want?

Using the `[p]` option on the `table` and `figure` floats means that they get pushed to their own 'float' page, as such "*the sequence of elements in the resulting DVI is NOT as it is in the TeX file.*"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[p]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1   &   2
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Table}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[p]
 \centering
 \rule{20pt}{10pt}
 \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example produces an out-of-sequence `figure` placement, based on the comments made here, as well as the TeX FAQ entry: [Two-column float numbers out of order](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2colfltorder)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{figure*}
  \centering\includegraphics{figure1}% This figure is on page 2
  \caption{First figure} \label{figure1}
\end{figure*}
Here is a reference to Figure~\ref{figure1}.
\lipsum[4-6]
\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics{figure2}% This figure is on page 1
  \caption{Second figure} \label{figure2}
\end{figure}
Here is a reference to Figure~\ref{figure2}.
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

[image: Figures out of sequence]

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text, while the `demo` package option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) allows for all images (existing or non-existent) to be replaced by a `150pt` x `100pt` black rectangle.

The reason for this out-of-sequence placement of figures (floats in general), is because TeX keeps separate FIFO lists for one- and two- column floats. Since the first `figure` is placed in the one-column float list (by using the starred version `*`) and the second is placed in the two-column float list but can still fit on the page, it is typeset first. The deferred first `figure` is typeset on page 2, since that's the default behaviour of multi-column spanning floats in two-column mode.

A solution is provided by using the [`fixltx2e` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) that uses a single FIFO list for deferred floats.

Answer (score 1):

You say: I wish to have a TeX example which includes text, ..., where the sequence of elements in the resulting DVI is NOT as it is in the TeX file.

Try to use:

```
\def\swap#1#2{#2 #1}

\swap {sequence of elements} {in resulting DVI} is NOT as in the TeX file.
\bye
```

Comment: The question is about ***floats***

Comment: We can `\swap` floats at macro level. Of course, `\insert` of single type is FIFO. We can use more `\insert` types. But this was mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Since you *deliberately* swap, where's the usefulness of this answer?

Comment: And where is usefulness of this question? The question says: I wish to have a TeX example which includes text, figures and tables, where the sequence of elements in the resulting DVI is NOT as it is in the TeX file. And the answer is: use `\swap` and elements are in different sequence in resulting DVI.